# Cannot install phpmyadmin

Tags: debian, apt, mysql, phpmyadmin

I cannod install phpmyadmin. The installation process fails with the following error. I can normally log in to the mysql database. What should I do? Normally I would expect "(using password: Yes)". What is making apt to not to bother to give the password?. I am using Debian 9 installation that is pretty fresh and installed on a clean hard drive.

I have copied the innoDB storage from the previous installation and the database has imported these (together with the *mysql* database)

Additionally AFAIK "dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server" should ask for root password. In my case nothing happens - command quits after one second.

[image: mysql error]

Comment: did you try the solution from Kishor Ramanan 
 on the following link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: Its completely unrelated to my problem. As I said I can log in to the database.

Comment: sorry then, I misunderstood your question (translation problem, in my country "normally" means "usually", sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 5):

I have figured it out.

**Solution 1**
The trick was: set "SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('')" apparently dbconfig-common works only if the password is empty.

This is  related to the contents of "/etc/mysql/debian.cnf" file which  in my case had empty password set:

```
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password =  
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = 
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

**Solution 2**

Put the password for the root user into /etc/mysql/debian.cnf

```
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = **** password here ***** 
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = **** password here *****
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

Comment: Placing passwords in readable text files is normally a security risk. Reader beware!

Comment: That is true, but that refused to install otherwise.